# Reboot Zyxel router via Telnet

Tags: router, telnet

I've got a Zyxel P-661HW-D1, I was wondering if anyone knows how to reboot it via telnet?

I can't seem to find the command...

Thanks,

Kieron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's the ZyXEL CLI reference](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/P-660HN-F1/cli_reference_guide/P-660HN-F1_1.pdf). At least it's ***a*** ZyXEL CLI reference. Not sure if it's exactly pertinent to your firmware version or device.

Give `sys reboot` a try. (see page 21 of the CLI reference for further info)

Comment: Superb, worked a treat, thanks.

Strange that it didn't show up under the sys command section.

Comment: in case that link ever goes down, also http://web.archive.org/web/20170409163105/http://www.zen76171.zen.co.uk/P-660HN-F1_1.pdf